# How to remove a user from a D2L group

Tags: desire2learn

There is a function for enrolling a user in a group:  POST /d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/groupcategories/(D2LID: groupCategoryId)/groups/(D2LID: groupId)/enrollments/, but I haven't been able to find a function for removing a user from a group.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is a gap in the REST routes in this area for currently released D2L Platforms (up to v10 SP1).  It is bit extreme, but prior to an api update, one work around would be to retreive the group enrollments and save them, then delete and recreate the group and enroll everyone except the delete target.